# HDLC Library for .NET?

Tags: .net

i wanna work with HDLC (High-Level Data Link Control) in .NET. 
is there any library?
thanks.

Comment: @John Saunders , I wanna work with modem (connect and send/receive data) via it. (if there's something in c/c++, NP, i'll work)

Comment: @user: ok, but why? Most people can find less painful things to do with their time. Also, isn't there already some networking software using the modem? Such software usually abstracts away such low-level details. It's been decades since I've even _heard_ the term "HDLC".

Comment: @John Saunders, Well i don't know. in fact my boss told me this. Maybe the target machine that talks to us just supports that or...

Answer (score 1):

Check this web page: 
[GuruX Open Source DLMS Implementation](http://www.gurux.fi/index.php?q=GuruxWeb)

DLMS uses HDLC protocol as Data Link Layer.